# How to remove duplicates list using Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

[image]

There are four records in the above table; how can i get result which will have unique id and get the latest record sorted by creation time using Java 8 streams.

In this example; I want to see only two records like this:

```
6838322 45210 2018-03-08 06:07
```

and

```
6838320 45209 2018-03-08 05:50
```

Comment: If that's a SQL table, why can't you find unique values at query time?

Comment: You will need an image processing/ paint tool to remove the lines from the picture. If you have a programming related task, you should describe that task in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourObjects.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
               YourObject::getId,
               YourObject::getCreationTime,
               BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Function.identity())
))
```

where `YourObject` is actually the object in java that you have and `getCreationTime` returns a `Date` that is `Comparable`.

Comment: This is personal taste, but I would have used `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, or just `(older, newer) -> older.isAfter(newer) ? older : newer`

Answer (score -1):

You can sort the stream by creationtime, and apply equality of records on id (so that you can use distinct). Following is the code:

```
public class StreamStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> datas = Arrays.asList(new Data(6838322, new Date()), new Data(6838320, new Date(1520574131111L)),
                new Data(6838320, new Date(1520574136940L)), new Data(6838320, new Date(324324353999L)));

        datas.stream()
            .sorted((d1, d2) -> d2.creationTime.compareTo(d1.creationTime))
            .distinct()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}

class Data {
    int id;
    Date creationTime;
    public Data(int id, Date creationTime) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Data other = (Data) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [id=" + id + ", creationTime=" + creationTime + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: this will not produce *records*, but only `Date`s, further `(d1, d2) -> d2.creationTime.compareTo(d1.creationTime)` can be simplified with `Comparator.comparing(Class::getCreationTime)`; also read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49190267/1059372

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks!